Memory fence with std::system_clock::now()
I need to add two memory fences into my codes, in order to prevent my codes from being reordered by either the compiler or CPU.
Like this:
rec.time_stamp0 = std::system_clock::now();
std::atomic_signal_fence( std::memory_order::release );
/*
  do many things...
*/
std::atomic_signal_fence( std::memory_order::acquire );
rec.time_stamp1 = std::system_clock::now();

Here I want to ensure that rec.time_stamp0 = std::system_clock::now(); certainly be executed before all other codes, and that rec.time_stamp1 = std::system_clock::now(); must be after all others.
My questions:

Does std::system_clock::now() natively come with a memory fence(it's a
syscall)? So explicit fence is not necessary?
Should I use std::atomic_thread_fence, or std::atomic_signal_fence
here(My program is single thread)?


Reading the current time isn't a memory operation on CPUs where there's a special instruction to do that.  On x86 for example, you'd want _mm_lfence if you need to be sure that all previous instructions have retired from out-of-order exec before an RDTSC in now() reads a timestamp.  (None of the standard atomic_thread_fence or signal_fence memory orders compile to lfence because it's useless for memory ordering, only for execution ordering. x86-64 usage of LFENCE)

Also related: How to get the CPU cycle count in x86_64 from C++?


std::system_clock::now() probably doesn't run lfence, and it's hopefully not a real system call that enters the kernel.  On x86-64 Linux at least, clock_gettime runs purely in user-space, using code+data the kernel maps into user-space-readable pages (VDSO) to run rdtsc and use it to interpolate since the last timer interrupt update to the system time.

